# How to execute "git push" via PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, git, git-push

I am trying to create a git commit and push it to the remote repo every time my client updates their Wordpress plugins or core. I have successfully hooked into the correct filter so I can execute php code once the updates are done, and I can even create a commit, but I have no luck  pushing to remote.

I am using the following code:

```
system ( 'cd '.ABSPATH.'; git add -A;' );
system ( 'cd '.ABSPATH.'; git commit -a -m "Updated plugins via WP";' );
system ( 'cd '.ABSPATH.'; echo `git push`;' );
```

The first 2 lines work great! They produce output as well. However, the 3rd line does NOT work. And there is no output produced. When I check my repo, the changes have not been pushed to remote. When I manually do `git push` via terminal/shell, it pushes successfully and it produces output.

I must be missing something obvious?

Comment: According to you, what's different from the 2 first lines and the last?

Comment: Do you intentionally do the push within the backticks? Did you try calling `system ( 'cd '.ABSPATH.'; git push;' );`

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php

You can try using Git.php to run git commands. While it does not have a `push` function, you can use the `run` function like this:

```
$repo = Git::open(ABSPATH);
$repo->add('-A');
$repo->commit('Updated plugins via WP');
$repo->run('push');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure whether using 'system()' is a great idea.
However there is SSH2 support in PHP, a great tutorial on how to interact with a server using SSH2 and PHP can be found here:

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/

( It even covers installing the ssh2 library if you haven't got it installed already )

Also you could try some intermediate 'echo''s through the system command just to see whether its still producing output.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd write a simple bash script to do your batch git operations and execute that with `proc_open` rather than using `system`. It's better for getting your script output as well as checking for errors and exit code.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the output, you have to echo it

```
echo system ( 'cd '.ABSPATH.'; echo `git push`;' );
```

Comment: Tried that, doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the echo and the backticks from the last line, you'll get the code you most likely would also use yourself:

```
system ( 'cd '.ABSPATH.'; git push ;' );
```

Note that a push will fail if your server is not running on `HEAD`. You may need to specify a branch name and need to `pull` before you `push`. (I would use pull - commit - push.)